# How to get more than 50 transitions in boost msm?

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost msm to implement HSM and I am at the point where the maximum number of transitions possible is 50. I looked at some blog posts and they said that if we create /mpl/vector/vector60.hpp, it should work. I tried and this is the error I get

[image]

I am wondering how I am generate these vector60, vector70.hpp .. files or map60, map70.hpp files so that I can get more transitions.

Comment: Look at the source code -- `libs/mpl/preprocessed`

Comment: Why all the close requests asking for MCVE? Based on Boost sources, 50 seems to be a limit of the files generated in MPL, and I've yet to find official documentation elaborating on this (I'd welcome to be proven wrong). At most a downvote for not digging through the source enough, since it didn't really take too long to find the Python scripts that appear to generate it. Nevertheless, is still seems like a useful question, and one that can be answered without further clarification.

Comment: surely its about time that mpl was modified to use variadics!!